# PFImageView causing memory issues (iOS SDK 8.2 + Parse)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Backstory: I'm creating an iOS app that loads data from a Parse backend onto tinder-style cards.  The data includes images. I'm using this for the cards: https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards.

When the app first launches, it pulls 5 rows from the database and loads some cards into an NSMutableArray.  Everytime a card is swiped left or right, another card is added to that array.

It's working fine, but as soon as I turn on images, everything breaks down.  Memory usage is off the charts and the app quickly crashes. Here's what it looks like with images loading:
Xcode Memory Debugger - each spike is from swiping a card and loading the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN8kp.png

When I comment out the image code, it runs fine with no memory issues.

The problem seems to be either:
1) how I'm loading cards
2) how I'm removing cards

I'm loading cards like this:

```
- (void)setupPhoto
{
    NSString *itemId = productId;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"itemId = %@",itemId];
    NSLog(@"itemId: %@",itemId);
    //now let's set up the query:
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"dailyItems" predicate:predicate];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        PFFile *itemFile = [object objectForKey:@"itemImage"];
        productPhoto.file = itemFile;
        [productPhoto loadInBackground];
    }];
}
```

Walkthrough:

1. Get the item's id.  This corresponds with the row in the Parse backend.
2. Query using a predicate to match that item's id
3. In the background, grab the PFFile that represents the image on the backend
4. productPhoto is a `PFImageView`, so I can set the file to the PFFile
5. call loadInBackground to grab the actual image

When I remove a card, I just say:

```
[card removeFromSuperview];
```

What do I have to do to get my memory in check?

Thank you so much!

Comment: They use shared NSCache which will be poured on memory warning.